# Finding schedules in resque - ruby

Tags: ruby, resque

I am using resque to process some background jobs (like cron jobs). So I fire these two rake tasks:
$> rake resque:work
$> rake resque:scheduler

My question is how to find worker and scheduler are running? For worker I can use

`Resque::Worker.all` lists all running workers. And it works fine. But I have not been able to find how to find scheduler is runnig or not (or list all scheduled jobs). I tried `Resque::Scheduler.print_schedule` but that does not print schedules and always returns epmty hash even if I have run `rake resque:scheduler`

Answer (score 2):

The method you need is

```
Resque.get_schedules
```

It displays a hash of currently scheduled jobs and their related metadata.

```
 {
    "job1"=> {
       "every"=>"30s",
       "class"=>"JobClass",
       "args"=>[1],
       "queue"=>"default",
       "description"=> "Testing..."
    }
}
```

If you aren't dynamically adding any jobs, i.e you aren't using the dynamic setting of resque-scheduler

```
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true
```

Then

```
Resque.schedule
```

will give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Am also searching for listing all the scheduled jobs...

```
Resque.count_all_scheduled_jobs
```

This displays the number only.

I tried a couple of methods in

```
Resque.metaclass.instance_methods-Class.methods
```

but no luck. Have to get into their Github source